Liability of a power of attorney agent for harm to an elderly principal while absent
Does an agent under a power of attorney or medical power of attorney, who has hired care givers five hours a day, but who does not live close to the principal and doesn't provide 24/7 care through third-parties, have liability if the principal hurts herself while a care giver is not there? Or is that liability reserved for a legal guardian?

This site can’t answer legal questions though you should always write out what an acronym means to ensure everyone understands what you are talking about.

I have edited the question so that it can be answered at this site and is not a question asking for specific legal advice.

The relationship between an agent under a durable power of attorney (either medical or non-medical) (POA) and the principal, upon whose behalf the agent acts, is a fiduciary relationship.
This means that the agent has a legal duty to use reasonable care when using the POA and must do so only in the best interests of the principal and not for self-interested reasons (although a POA can authorize reasonable compensation for work done in connection with the POA).
This duty is not all encompassing. A POA gives the agent authority to do certain things that otherwise the principal would have to do, and the POA imposes legal obligations on the agent regarding how that power is used.
But, unlike a guardian, a POA agent does not have 24/7 responsibility for the principal and unlike a guardian, a POA agent can't compel the principal to do or refrain from doing anything. A POA is a power to say yes to something, but not a power to say no to the principal.
If the POA agent did have liability for reasons unrelated to misappropriating the principal's funds or otherwise putting the agent's own personal interests above the principal in a POA authorized transaction, it would be for failing to use reasonable care in carrying out tasks using the POA.
For example, if POA agent hired someone who had just been released from prison for killing her patients while she was a nurse to be a caregiver, without doing any due diligence, the POA agent might have liability if the caregiver then tried to harm to principal.
But, if five hours a week of care is what the principal reasonably needs and can afford, and there is some way for the principal to get emergency help or be checked in on, in an emergency, this probably meets the standard of care for a family member with a POA. So, the family member POA agent would probably not have liability to the principal in this situation.
On the other hand, if a qualified medical professional told the POA agent that the principal is almost sure to die or seriously hurt herself if she is unattended for nineteen hours a day, and there are economic means available to get a higher level of care, then this could be a breach of duty, if the POA agent could have convinced the principal to get a higher level of care.
Indeed, if skimping on care appeared to be motivated by a desire to inherit a larger amount at the principal's death, this could even be viewed as a form of disloyalty, playing the agent's future economic benefits above the principal's current health needs.
Often, however, elderly principals are in denial and are so afraid of going to a nursing home that they don't get the care that they need. If that is why more care is not obtained, then the fault is not with the POA agent, but with the principal. But, while there would be no legal liability for inaction in that situation, a good family member would seek a guardianship in a case like that, in order to gain the power to compel the principal to seek the necessary level of care over the principal's objections. Usually, a POA agent is high on the list of persons with priority for appointment as a guardian for the principal, if one is needed.
A care giver or treating medical professional of the principal could also have liability if a higher level of care was clearly necessary, but the care giver or treating medical professional didn't make this clear to the principal or the POA agent, and harm to the principal occurred while a care giver was not there.

Thanks for the reply. She has told me she doesn't want them (caregivers) there as much as they are (5 hours a day x 7 days a week), and will not go to a NF. I have also offered to accommodate her in my home in Florida (she is in Texas) full time, but she will not part with her cats which I'm allergic to. They cannot financially accommodate (nor does she desire) a 24/7 caregiver without eventually bankrupting themselves. They are not wealthy by normal standards. As her POA I cannot force her to do anything. I am too far away to become guardian. I am also her husbands POA/MPOA.

Her husband is in a NF, and I have helped him secure Medicaid through legal counsel for that so he is good, but I am now trying to help her while she is still able to reside in her home. Unfortunately I am the only person they trust. They made that crystal clear in their wills. I am just doing what I can....
